# Firebase read data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get all the latitude and longitude from firebase database from the following provided structure? Not able to get data inside the push key node as it randomly generated I am not able to catch it.

DEVICE_ID-COORDINATES->DATE->PUSHKEY (EX:-KSHJDWFQ)->NOW get the CHILD LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE.
Thank you in advance.
Please help

```
 {
  "Driver2" : {
    "1_353490067508933" : {
      "coordinates" : {
        "18-11-2017" : {
          "-KzDdfZtds7rxwETF4oN" : {
            "latitude" : "22.5735663",
            "longitude" : "88.4317749"
          },
          "-KzDl67WgnmKlYADN4sE" : {
            "latitude" : "22.5736048",
            "longitude" : "88.4316857"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**this is what i have done**

```
        final String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
        fb_ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL_STARTED);
        fb_ref.child("1_353490067508933").limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    //Driver post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Driver.class);
                    //Log.d("DataNodee", post.getDri_lat());
                    //Log.d("DataNodee", post.getDri_lng());
                    // updatemap(Double.parseDouble(post.getDri_lat()), Double.parseDouble(post.getDri_lng()));
                    for (com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot Driver : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String childKey = Driver.getKey();
                        Log.d("childKey", childKey);
                        firebase_url_coordinates = "https://pool-xyz.firebaseio.com/Driver2/1_353490067508933/" + childKey + "/coordinates/" + date + ".json";
                        Log.d("json_url", firebase_url_coordinates);
                        makeJsonObjectRequest();
                    }
                    LCUtils.showToastShort(mContext, "Found");
                } else {
                    LCUtils.showToastShort(mContext, "Not Found");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: did the answer work?

Comment: let me try i will sure let you know

Comment: it's not returning anything.But the code works fine

Comment: check the edit in the answer to see what the log will give you

Comment: yes i have already log the value but the debugger is not getting inside reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { this method

Comment: okay I have updated the lines before this reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {. Also be sure that the child() are correct same as in your database, now it should work I added `child("Driver2")`

Comment: Yes now it works thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159336/discussion-between-avik-and-peter-haddad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference reference = database.child("Driver2").child("Device_id_here").child("coordinates").child("date_here");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {  
     for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
       String latitude=data.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
         String longs=data.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
         Log.i("latitude", latitude);
         Log.i("longtitude",longs);
    }
    }
     @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

So according to this:

DEVICE_ID-COORDINATES->DATE->PUSHKEY (EX:-KSHJDWFQ)->NOW get the CHILD LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE.

You have the id and date, the problem was in the `pushkey`. So you have to query on the `child("date")` and then do a for loop that will iterate inside the `pushkeys` thus giving you the `longitude` and `latitude` values.